# is too long. Maximum length is 128. while using double quotes

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I have a SP in MSSQL that will insert and error log to the SQL

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestLog]


@PrimaryName nvarchar(255),
@ERROR nvarchar(4000)

AS
BEGIN


insert into Process_Log 
(
PrimaryName ,
ERROR
) VALUES
(
@PrimaryName ,
@ERROR
)

END
```

My sample error message is this:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__AP__2EC21549E681BC94'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Test'. The duplicate key value is (215009).
The statement has been terminated.
```

as I have the ' in string I have to use double quotes and SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF.

I am unable to change the error message or edit it as it is from other application.

EDIT:

My Process table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Process_Log](
    [PrimaryName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ERROR] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
```

Comment: So what's the issue here?  Did you know that you can also replace `'` with `''` and this will work just as well as double quotes, etc.?

Comment: Yes I know, but as I said I am unable to edit the error message. It has to stay as it is. and when I use SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF and the len of the string is more than 128 SQL throws and error (len too long). I tried to do left(@ERROR, 128) but it is not working with values in double quotes.

Comment: your error message field would be well suited to varchar(max) - I often see error logs where messages/stack traces are stored as long fields, but key messages can end up having to be truncated.  Some people had a 2 hour meeting about how long to make their error table, unaware of data-types text, varchar(max) etc.

Comment: My table has nvarchar(MAX) for Error field.

Comment: in your procedure it is limited to 4000 characters on the parameter though

Comment: I suspect your quotes are causing the assignment to pick up other stuff from your code, what is actually in your field?

Comment: Oh, I know as I was testing with field len in SP trying to fix my error. Well spotted anyway!

Comment: In my field will be the error message that I have posted in my question, thats all. (not sure of that was your question)

Comment: I'm not understanding. If you already have the error message, it's presumably in a `(n)varchar` of some sort and the *contents* do not have to have anything special done - the single quote characters no longer have meaning. Unless you're using *dynamic* SQL somewhere (that you've not shown us), and usually the right thing to do there is to stop doing dynamic SQL (or at least, for strings such as this, keep the string in a variable/parameter and away from the dynamic part).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for that: I have to execute the SP with SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF before exec SP, I had SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF - in my SP - but it has to be executed every time I execute SP. (SP is executed in the software.)

Example:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
Exec [TestLog]
@PrimaryName = "test"
,@ERROR = "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__AP__2EC21549E681BC94'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Test'. The duplicate key value is (215009).
The statement has been terminated."
```

Then I will avoid a a 128 len probmem.

Answer (score 1):

In your query replace:

```
insert into Process_Log 
(
PrimaryName ,
ERROR
) VALUES
(
@PrimaryName ,
@ERROR
)
```

with:

```
insert into Process_Log 
(
PrimaryName ,
ERROR
) VALUES
(
@PrimaryName ,
REPLACE(@ERROR, '''', '''''')
)
```

This is NOT changing the error message, just "escaping" the single quotes so that SQL Server won't get confused.

You will also need to get rid of the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` bit and forget about double quotes.

---

I'm starting to think that this isn't SQL Server, as that "stuff" you added in your comment below certainly isn't SQL as I know it... and it doesn't do anything if I try running it through SSMS.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (error VARCHAR(MAX));
--Doesn't work due to single quotes
--INSERT INTO @test SELECT 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__AP__2EC21549E681BC94'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Test'. The duplicate key value is (215009). The statement has been terminated.';
INSERT INTO @test SELECT 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint ''PK__AP__2EC21549E681BC94''. Cannot insert duplicate key in object ''dbo.Test''. The duplicate key value is (215009). The statement has been terminated.';
SELECT * FROM @test;
```

Comment: I don't think it will work, as the syntax without "" will be wrong, right? (Incorrect syntax near PK__...)

Comment: Nope, you are incorrect, try it... you might be surprised!  Basically it will replace `'` with `''`, then SQL Server will in turn replace `''` back to `'`.  It's just telling the query engine that when you have `'` to save it as part of the message rather than seeing it as the end of the message.

Comment: declare #test nvarchar(255)
set #test 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__AP__2EC21549E681BC94'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Test'. The duplicate key value is (215009).
The statement has been terminated.'

select replace(#test, '''', '''''')     ERROR MESSAGE: Incorrect syntax near 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint '.  (Preplace #  with @)

Answer (score 0):

If the column does not support strings with, then you will need to `alter` your `TestLog` `table` and increase the size of the column which was truncated. You can learn how to alter a table in MS SQL here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

You will need to change your parameter from

```
@ERROR nvarchar(4000)
```

to

```
@ERROR nvarchar(MAX)
```

Also, you will need to take a look at how many characters your error message is and act accordingly.

And also, you will need to make sure your quotes are properly escaped.

Comment: No sorry, it will not work. It will work with a string value like 'hello word' or even with "hello word" but if I will have "some random error with more than 128 char len" SQL will error.

Comment: @Lemon please show us the structure of your TestLog table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Process_Log](
 [PrimaryName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [ERROR] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)

Comment: @Lemon how long is primary name you intend to insert into the table?

Comment: less than 20 char for now? I don't think it will be ever longer than 255 - is is there just for test.

Comment: @Lemon can you check it out, just to make sure it is really less than 20 chars? You could run a select using LEN to find this out just before you try to insert it. The error message clearly tells you that the problem is with violating the primary key.

Comment: Yes, that's the error message from Application, not from the SP and my task is to save this error in the Process_log table, so it has nothing to do with PK.

Comment: @Lemon try to execute your stored procedure without the application but with the same values your application was trying to execute it. What the result will be? My guess is that the application throws an error it gets from your Stored Procedure as a response.

Comment: Yes If I will execute the SP in sql with the same error message I will get the same error. (I was testing the SP in SQL only as the application crashed yesterday and I was trying to fix the SP.)

Comment: @Lemon then the error is in the SP. Read again my comment about running a select involving LEN.

Comment: I know its the len! in the Error variable right? I am 100% sure its not from the 1st field. Error will fail as it has "" - and SQL support the len in this type only up to 128 char long - If it has more then it will throw and Len error, right? using "" is similar to []. but I have to have my string in "" as I am unable to edit the error message in the app. So I think there is no workaround on that one :<

Comment: Try inserting '' instead of @ERROR. Will this crash as well?

Comment: No. I will give an example:  if #ERROR = 'this value has more than 128 char len' - sql will insert it. #ERROR = 'this values has extra' quote' - SQL will error with incorrect syntax. So I decided to use SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF and do something like that: #ERROR = "this values has extra quote but less than' 128len" -- sql will insert BUT, #ERROR = "values extra quote ' and more than 128 char len" - SQL will error with: [...]is too long. Maximum length is 128.

Comment: You will need to escape the quotes.